# Escape % character in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to save a char which contains, among others %, but the problem is that while other characters such as ' / or " seem to work just fine, I just can't figue out how to escape %. I tried many things, but using mysql_real_escape_string or other stuff just don't work.

At the moment, I'm replacing % with 'percent' (it didn't work with backslash + %), saving that to the database, and then replacing it back before echoing, but as you may notice, it's not really optimal. Please let me know if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Why do you want to escape the `%` character? What gets stored when you try to store this symbol in database?

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't store it at all, that's why I assumed I have to escape it. Also, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html

Comment: Usually you escape it when you use it inside `LIKE` clause and want to match the literal `%`. Are you using `sprintf` function to build your insert/update queries by any chance?

Comment: I don't think so, sorry but I'm no database expert, this is part of a wordpress plugin, here's the file for all the querys http://pastebin.com/QGVQNHxS

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to put variable values in-line with the query. Use placeholders and value binding.

Answer (score 1):

If in php you need to use **addslashes** to percent character before inserting.
for mysql its:

```
'10\% off' //you need to escape % character
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will not change % character while doing an insert/update. If you are having problems with it, it must be some other layer in your setup which is doing the conversion.

```
create table test ( a varchar(10));
insert into test values ('abc%def');
select * from test;

+---------+
| a       |
+---------+
| abc%def | 
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Ok then, there must be something wrong with the query or something else, the problem is that I really don't know much about mysql, this is the code pastebin.com/QGVQNHxS

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the `%` can be escaped by making it double, so a quite simple `str_replace` did it for me.